# Cargar Plantilla de Bootstrap 5 en componentes vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5, vue3, laravel-9

Estoy utilizando laravel 9 integrado con vuejs 3 en el mismo proyecto.
Descargue una plantilla de bootstrap5 y la dividí en: Cabecera, Footer y Menu. Quiero que este dinámicamente su funcionalidad utilizando vuejs para evitar el recargue de la pagina a cliquear a cualquier modulo.

Esta es la plantilla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo **resources/js/app.js** donde importo el componente principal de vue

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from '../components/routes.js';
import App from '../components/layouts/App.vue'

//componente principal de vue
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app")
```

Este es la ruta **web.php** donde carga la vista view de laravel

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// proporciona un punto de entrada para cualquier solicitud GET que 
// no se corresponda con una ruta existente, permitiendo que una 
// aplicación de una sola página hecha con Vue.js pueda gestionar
// todas las solicitudes de rutas en el lado del cliente.

  Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('main');
  })->where('any', '.*');
```

Esta es la vista **main** de laravel donde esta el div para inicializar vuejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Aplicacion de gestion de calidad" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>GE2 - Gestión de calidad</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/umd/simple-datatables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/datatables-simple-demo.js')}}"></script>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')

  </body>
</html>
```

este es el archivo **routes.js** donde estan las rutas de vuejs

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [

];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Componente **Cabezera.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <!-- Navbar Brand-->
            <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!-- Navbar Search-->
            <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Navbar-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Activity Log</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import logo from '../../asset/img/redgesencro_blanco.png';

export default {
  name: "Cabezera",
  setup() {
    return {
        logo: logo,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Componente **Menu.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                    Dashboard
                </a>
                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Interface</div>
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseLayouts"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
                    Layouts
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseLayouts" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                    <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="layout-static.html">Static Navigation</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="layout-sidenav-light.html">Light Sidenav</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsePages"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></div>
                    Pages
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapsePages" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                    <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav accordion" id="sidenavAccordionPages">
                        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseAuth"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseAuth">
                            Authentication
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseAuth" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                            <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseError" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseError">
                            Error
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseError" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                            <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="401.html">401 Page</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="500.html">500 Page</a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Addons</div>
                <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i></div>
                    Charts
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                    Tables
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Menu",
    setup() {
        return {};
    },
};
</script>
```

Componente **Footer.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
      <div class="container-fluid px-4">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
          <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2023</div>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            &middot;
            <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Footer",
  setup() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

Componente vue principal **App.vue**

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <Cabezera />
        <Menu />
        <!-- Rutas Vue.js aquí -->
        <router-view></router-view>
        <p>prueba</p>
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Cabezera from './Cabezera.vue';
import Menu from './Menu.vue';
import Footer from './Footer.vue';
export default {
    components: {
        Cabezera,
        Menu,
        Footer,
    }
}

</script>
```

Al ejecutarlo evidencio que si esta vuejs cargado pero la plantilla se desorganiza y pierde funcionalidad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo lo solucioné alguna vez

router.js

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/pokemon'
},
{
    path: '/pokemon',
    name: 'pokemon',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "PokemonLayout"*/'@/modules/pokemon/layouts/PokemonLayout'),
    children: [
        {
            path: 'home', 
            name: 'pokemon-home',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ListPage"*/'@/modules/pokemon/pages/ListPage')
        }
    ]
}
```

]

PokemonLayout.vue

```
<template>
<div class="pokemon-layout">
    <h1>Pokemon Layout</h1>
    <!-- Acá puedes poner el resto de componentes generales -->
    <router-view></router-view>
    <!-- Acá puedes poner el resto de componentes generales -->
</div>
```

ListPage.vue

```
<template><h1>List Page</h1></template>
```